# How to hide the query rendering in airflow (hide secrets from logs)

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query in snowflake to share data to AWS S3. I have to enter the access keys in the query.
How can I hide the query rendering in airflow?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE MY_STAGE
    url='s3://my_bucket/others'
  credentials=(
      aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      aws_secret_key='DFgsdFGSdfgAqTRjfFGHJ343'
      aws_token='hsfdjfhksdfhskdfhsdkjfhiauowqegkhbHSALDfkshdfisuhiqwuger8748sf0!$#%FGH#$%'
)
```

Comment: Create your stage beforehand or with storage integrations: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving Simon's answer from comment to answer, for closure:

Create your stage beforehand or with storage integrations.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html

If you create the stage beforehand, then you can just reference it by name, without the need to type credentials again.

Comment: What about if it's rendering secret for redshift unload data?